# D3 in Meteor is creating new shapes with updated data, rather than updating existing shape

Tags: javascript, d3.js, meteor

I am using D3 in Meteor to create a simple rectangle whose measurements will change based on calculations run in a global helper.  I have replicated a simpler version of my code in [this Meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/wCS6xsF9xefTLvyYt/D3%20in%20Meteor%20(finance)).

When the user clicks one of the buttons, the `activeValue` changes and the width of the rectangle should change,  Instead, it is creating a new rectangle, using the width from the new `activeValue` each time the user clicks a button.  The existing shape is not changed.

I added `var data = Template.currentData()`, as [discussed here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2010).  However, I'm not sure if I am using it properly.

Am I missing something specific to D3?

Thank you.

EDIT
I've been able to use @nchenbang's code in both the MeteorPad and my working app and now see the changes in value.  However, there is still a problem when adding more `Results`.  I revised [the MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/wCS6xsF9xefTLvyYt/D3%20in%20Meteor%20(finance)) to illustrate.  When I add a second `Result` and then change the value, it only controls the first `Result`, not the new one.

I'm thinking it has something to do with the line `d3.select("rect")`, but I can't figure out how to change it. How can I make sure the code runs for each `Result` separately?

Comment: as I see it (never worked with d3 so far) your problem seems to be in the onRendered-method, which is always called "onclick" and because of their's no check if the element is actually existing, it always just `append`s a new one. Hope this helps you out. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

After studying through your code in the Meteorpad (still not really sure what you are trying to do in overall), I realized that you are using the blaze data context wrongly. For your template's js, you can access the data of your template by using `this.data` in your `Template.Result.onRendered` or `this` in your template's events and helpers. For your template's html, you can directly access the data by using the name, for example calling `{{_id}}` will give you the _id of current template.

Note that I am using `Template.currentData()` in the `self.autorun` to access the data context of current template instead of `self.data` because `Template.currentData()` is reactive which means whenever the value of option for the current template changes, the D3's transform in `self.autorun` can rerun and change the width of the rectangle.

Below are my modifications on your Result template

client/app.js(modify Result template only)

```
Template.Result.events({
  'click #result1': function(e) {
    (e).preventDefault();

    Results.update({_id:this._id},{$set:{option: this.rate1}});
  },
  'click #result2': function(e) {
    (e).preventDefault();

    Results.update({_id:this._id},{$set:{option: this.rate2}});
  }  
});

Template.Result.helpers({
  getResult: function(rate) {
    return getResult(rate);
  }
});

Template.Result.onRendered (function () {
  const self = this;
  let barContainer = d3.select("#bar" + self.data._id)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("height", 50),
     bar = barContainer.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("height", 50)
    .attr("width", getResult(self.data.option || 0));

  self.autorun(() => {
    let option = Template.currentData().option;

    if(option !== self.data.option)
    {
      barContainer.select("rect")
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("height", 50)
      .attr("width", getResult(option));
    };
  });
});

let getResult = (rate) => {
    var multiplier = 10;

    return rate * multiplier;
};
```

main.html(modify Result template only)

```
<template name="Result">
  <div class="result">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="wrapper grid">
        <div class="grid-button">
          <button type="button" class="button" id="result1">
            {{getResult rate1}}
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-button">
          <button type="button" class="button" id="result2">
            {{getResult rate2}}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid wrapper">
        <div>          
          Click button to change the active value.  This should change the width of the rectangle.
        </div>
        <div>
          Active Value: {{getResult option}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div id="bar{{_id}}">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to use this code but still have an issue on updating separate Results (I can only change the first one). Can you please take a look at my edit above, as well as the revised MeteorPad?  Much appreciated.

Comment: Can you have a try of my newly updated answer and see if the final result is what you are expecting? If yes, I will try to explain what my modifications do. Sorry I did not really understand what you are trying to do before this since I only looked through your Result template `onRendered` callback

Comment: Thank you!  I'll need to spend some time with your answer to make sure I have proper reactivity throughout. In the meantime, you solved my most immediate need with `barContainer.select("rect")` (replacing `d3.select`).  Each `Result` now updates independently.  I probably over-simplified my code in the original post, losing the intent - I have dozens of financial calculations, each with multiple data dependencies, that I need to access in multiple templates (for shapes) and within calculations in other helpers.  I keep these calculations in in a global helper.  Thanks again.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you are keeping your calculations in a global helper? If you just want your calculations to be accessible from everywhere in client javascript files, you can use [modules](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/using-the-module-pattern-with-meteor/) which is a much more elegant solution.

Comment: I have a global helper `getResults` that contains all of the calculations and that I use in client javascript, as well as a second global helper `results` that calls `getresults()` and that I use in client HTML.  I'd have to study Modules if that is a better solution - this is literally the first app I have ever built so I'm learning as I go.  Thanks.